# Does openwhisk composer support docker?

Tags: python, docker, serverless, openwhisk

I worked on openwhisk to create python data science pipeline, it worked by using Docker because I am using numpy and other libraries. 
I tried to work on openwhisk composer to do multiple data science pipelines but the problem I faced is docker not supported, am I right or I am doing something wrong?

I wrote a simple python data science code which by importing python libraries like numpy, I created it as an actions in the OpenWhisk composer by typing (pydeploy) then when i invoked the action it pritn this error:

```
/composer_codebase/sample_code$ bx wsk action invoke test_composer_action --result { "in": {}, "msg": "Data --- ['/pythonAction', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '../actionProxy'] :: posix.uname_result(sysname='Linux', nodename='action', release='4.4.0-148-generic', version='#174-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 7 12:20:14 UTC 2019', machine='x86_64')" }
```

Comment: What **exactly** did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: Please update your question with the information. Code in comments is not readable.